Petersen’s proof of the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem
I was studying the proof of the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem, and the various lemmata that lead to it.
Since I couldn’t understand my professor’s proof (and he also acknowledged it was flawed), I researched for the one found in Petersen - Riemannian Geometry (Springer), Section 6.3 Nonpositive Sectional Curvature.
Petersen fixes a point $p \in M$, a vector $w \in T_p M$ and attempts to prove that $ | D \exp_p (w)  | \geq 0$, for all $w$, with equality holding when $w = 0$; $D$ represents the pushforward differential.
To do this, Petersen considers a geodesic $\gamma(t) = \exp_p (t v) $;
then the (unique) Jacobi vector field, along $\gamma$, such that $J(0) = 0$, and $\nabla_t J(0) = w$.
Petersen then crudely says

Then $ | D \exp_p (w)  | = | J(1) |$.

I have trouble understanding this passage. I am baffled. How is the last identity true?
Thanks in advance.

Yes, because $D\exp_p(w)=J(1)$. This is probably shown in the book but it’s also a reasonable exercise that tests your understanding of the exponential map, Jacobi fields, and how they’re related.

Yes. Thank you a lot. But I have been trying to solve the “exercise” all day long. Any hint?

Do you understand that Jacobi fields come from infinitesimal variations of geodesics? If you do, you can solve this problem.

Here's my attempt, though I am not sure it is fully correct.
We want to compute $\mathrm d _ \vec{v} [\exp _p] (\vec w)$, with $\vec w \perp \vec v$.
We use the kinematic interpretation of the differential, which means that we're looking for a curve
$ \sigma : (-\varepsilon ; + \varepsilon) \to T_p M$, such that
$$ \sigma (0) = \vec v, \quad \dot \sigma (0) = \vec w.$$
A good choice is $\sigma (s) = \vec v + s \vec w.$ So:
$$ \mathrm d _ \vec{v} [\exp _p] (\vec w) \; = \; \mathrm d _ \vec{v} [\exp _p] (\dot \sigma (0)) \; = \; \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \bigg \rvert _{s = 0} (\exp_p \circ \, \sigma)(s) \; = \; \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \bigg \rvert _{s = 0} \big (\exp_p(\vec v + s \vec w) \big ) \; = \; \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \bigg \rvert _{s = 0} \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t = 1)$$
Where $\gamma_{p, \, \vec v}(t)$ is my professor's notation to denote the (unique) geodesic starting from point $p$ with direction $\vec v$.
Now, let's make a few observations:
$s \mapsto \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t)$ is a variation of curves, where each longitudinal curve is a geodesic. By definition, this is a Jacobi variation, in the sense that its variation vector field along $\gamma_{p, \, \vec v}(t)$ will be a Jacobi vector field.
So $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \big \rvert _{s = 0}  \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t)$ is precisely the vector field that provides the variation.
We know that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \big \rvert _{s = 0}  \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t) = \tilde J(t) $ is a Jacobi vector field along $\gamma_{p, \, \vec v}(t)$. Let us observe two key properties of $\tilde J(t)$.
First:
$$ \tilde J (0) \, =\,  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \bigg \rvert _{s = 0}  \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(0) \, = \, \vec 0,$$
this is due to the fact that the many curves in the variation all have the same starting point, which means that the variation vector must be initially zero.
Secondly,
$$ \nabla_t \tilde J (0) = \nabla_t \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \bigg \rvert _{s = 0}  \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(0) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \nabla_t \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t) \bigg \rvert _{t=0, \, s=0}$$
where I've exchanged the two derivatives with the symmetry lemma,
$$ \nabla_t \tilde J (0) \, = \, \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \nabla_t \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t) \bigg \rvert _{t=0, \, s=0} \, = \,   \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s}\bigg \rvert _{s=0} (\vec v + s \vec w) \, \equiv \, \vec w \bigg \rvert _{s=0} \, = \, \vec w,$$
where we've used the fact that the curves are geodesics, so their velocities are constantly equal to the initial vector.
So $\tilde J (t)$ is a Jacobi field satisfying $\tilde J(0) = \vec 0$ and $\nabla _ t \tilde J (0) = \vec w$.
By the uniqueness of Jacobi fields, it must be that $\tilde J(t) = J(t)$, the original Jacobi field we had come up with.
So finally,
$$ \mathrm d _ \vec{v} [\exp _p] (\vec w) \; = \; \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \bigg \rvert _{s = 0} \gamma_{p, \, \vec v + s \vec w}(t = 1) \, = \, \tilde J(1) \, = \, J(1).$$

I'll provide the first few steps:
First, the equation you quote is not quite right. The corrected formula is $$D_w\exp_p(v) = J(1). $$ By the definition, the left side is the directional derivative of the map $\exp_p: T_pM \rightarrow M$ at $v$ in the direction $w$, $$D_w\exp_p(v) = \left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0}\exp_p(V(t)), $$ where $$V: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow T_pM$$ satisfies $V(0)=v$ and $V'(0)=w$. On the other hand, the map $$\Gamma: (-\delta,\delta) \times [0,1] \rightarrow M$$ given by $$\Gamma(s,t) = \exp_p(sV(t)) $$ is a $1$-parameter family of constant speed geodesics. I'll let you finish it from here.
More generally, the differential of the exponential map
\begin{align*}
\exp: T_*M &\rightarrow M\\
(p,v) &\mapsto \exp_p(v)
\end{align*}
can always be described in terms of Jacobi fields with specified values for $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$. So I always recommend translating any question about the differential of the exponential map into one about Jacobi fields, which I find much easier to work with.
